# Post parameters are undefined in express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, httprequest, httpresponse

I am learning MEAN stack for Web dev. I have following code on the client side:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost:3000/Sad/3',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': "Text"
 },
 data: {ID: Auth.sadit , UID: $scope.Sodid , PID: 1234}
};
```

and following is on the Server side :

```
app.post('/Sad/:Type', function(req, res) { 
        var param = req.data;
        var qry   = req.headers;
        var url   =req.url;
        console.log(req.data + "\n");
        if(req.params.Type == 1){
            <print all the parameters in request>
        }
        if(req.params.Type == 3){
            <Print the parameters in the request , change them and send it back>
            }

        res.status(200).send( " Hello User");
        });
```

Now when I try to print the parameters sent in the data from the client express gives me only undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are sending a json to the api, so `content-type` should be `application/json` instead of `text`.

Comment: i would also use $http or $resource

Comment: yup, I use $http myself.

Comment: Following code is on the cleint side and i am using http service                        app.controller('cont', [
'$scope',
'AU',
'$http',
function($scope, AU, $http){
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost:3000/Sad/3',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json"
 },
 data: {ID: Auth.sadit , UID: $scope.Sodid , PID: 1234}
};   
$http(req).then(

function(){
Auth.satid += 1;
console.log("sent the request" + req.data);
}, 

function(){
console.log(" failed ");
});        

in wireshark i see the http packet carries these values as jason object but i cant parse them in express